# Is there a best practice for resistor placement?

Tags: resistors

Resistors are color-coded by digit, multiplier, then tolerance, but the book I'm reading (comes with the Arduino starter kit) shows its breadboard diagrams with all the resistor tolerance bands leftmost, which seems backwards to me. I understand that resistors are not polarity sensitive, so they **can** go either way, but I was wonder if there was some sort of best practice / convention people use (read order vs reverse-read order).

Comment: Really is whatever you like.  I suggest picking something and sticking with it, but it's hard to read them wrong because of a wrong orientation.

Comment: You may end up joining the SMD master-race and have the cute little numbers written on top of the resistors, then it's just a matter of orienting them during placement so from the expected viewing angle, the values could be read quickly. Or blank, so it's harder for people to reverse engineer your circuit without removing components to test them..

Comment: Tolerance bands should be pointing North-West.  [Sorry, I couldn't resistor.]

Comment: @NickAlexeev: no, tolerance bands should be on the south-east (should that be "south or east"?) end of the resistor (or are you in Australia?)  :-)

Comment: Most people don't care, and the machines don't seem to care either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **text on your PCB** will be in some orientation.

If you make the color codes with tolerance band on the right **when the text reads right** (regardless of how the PCB ends up being mounted with respect to the gravity vector) that's probably optimal. And tolerance band at the bottom when the text reads right if they are mounted vertically (or avoid designing the board with non-horizontal resistors!).

This is kind of a nitpicking thing that few really care about in production situations- resistors often end up being mounted any which way. SMT parts (newer ones) of 0603 and smaller size are often completely blank. You learn to read the 3-digit (5% resistors) 3-character (E96 series) codes and color codes upside down or right side up fairly quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I like to place resistors so that the colour bands read left-to-right or top-to-bottom.

For resistors (usually surface-mount) with values printed on them in digits, they should read right from the bottom or left of the board.